# Library that converts a Python output string to an Elisp data structure?

Tags: python, formatting

Say that I evaluate the following Python code:

```
import inspect
import scipy.ndimage.filters

list (inspect.getargspec (scipy.ndimage.filters.gaussian_filter1d))
# => [['input', 'sigma', 'axis', 'order', 'output', 'mode', 'cval'],
#      None, None, (-1, 0, None, 'reflect', 0.0)]
```

I'd like to transform the output string, which is simply Python's
print output, to an Elisp data structure. So I need a function `foo`
that does this:

```
(foo "[['input', 'sigma', 'axis', 'order', 'output', 'mode', 'cval'], None, None, (-1, 0, None, 'reflect', 0.0)]")
;; =>
;; (("input"
;;   "sigma"
;;   "axis"
;;   "order"
;;   "output"
;;   "mode"
;;   "cval")
;;  nil
;;  nil
;;  (-1 0 nil "reflect" 0.0))
```

While it's not hard to write a version of `foo` that works for this
specific instance, I wonder if there's a library that does this in a
generic way, i.e. it is able to handle any complex Python structure.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Use JSON, not Python syntax

What you are looking for is [`json.el`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/tree/lisp/json.el) which is a part of Emacs.

Note that it will *not* read Python format OOTB; there are *at least* 3 problems:

1. `'foo'` is not recognized as a string
2. keywords `true`/`false`/`null` are recognized instead of `True`/`False`/`None`
3. tuples `(1,"bar")` are not recognized

### Full solution using json.dumps in Python

Python can easily print its data structures as [JSON](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html):

```cl
(require 'json)
(require 'python)
(json-read-from-string
 (substring
  (python-shell-send-string-no-output
   "import inspect, json; json.dumps (inspect.getargspec (json.dumps))"
   (run-python))
  1 -1))
==>
[["obj" "skipkeys" "ensure_ascii" "check_circular" "allow_nan"
  "cls" "indent" "separators" "encoding" "default" "sort_keys"]
 nil "kw" [:json-false t t t nil nil nil "utf-8" nil :json-false]]
```